Calculating the numerical flux in local Riemann problem
I am reading the following material:
https://www.i2m.univ-amu.fr/perso/kai.schneider/PDF-FILES/gdsmd_apnum_2015final.pdf
I am trying to figure out how to obtain the equation 7 from equations 5 and 6. They are as follows.
Equation 5: $\frac{\partial B_x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}=0$,
Equation 6: $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}+c_h^2\frac{\partial B_x}{\partial x} = -\frac{c_h^2}{c_p^2}\psi$,
Equation 7: $\begin{bmatrix}B_{x,m} \\ \psi_m\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}B_{x,L} \\ \psi_L\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}(B_{x,R}-B_{x,L})-\frac{1}{2c_h}(\psi_R-\psi_L) \\ \frac{1}{2}(\psi_R-\psi_L) - \frac{c_h}{2}(B_{x,R}-B_{x,L})\end{bmatrix}$.

Below is what I obtained so far, the linear system:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \begin{bmatrix}B_x \\ \psi\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ c_h^2 & 0\end{bmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\begin{bmatrix}B_x \\ \psi\end{bmatrix}=0$
the eigenvalues and the corresponding (right) eigenvectors of \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ c_h^2 & 0\end{bmatrix} is:
$\lambda_1=c_h, \quad r_1=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{c_h} \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$,
$\lambda_2=-c_h, \quad r_2=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{c_h} \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.
Also the left eigenvectors can be found by $L=R^{-1}$, that is,
$l_1 = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{c_h}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$,
$l_2 = \begin{bmatrix}-\frac{c_h}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$.
But then I can't figure out how to obtain the numerical fluxes (Eq. 7) based on these eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Updated:
I attempted to continue the steps, they seem to be close the equation 7, but there is something wrong.
Define: $U_L = \begin{bmatrix}B_{x,L} \\ \psi_L \end{bmatrix}$, $U_R = \begin{bmatrix}B_{x,R} \\ \psi_R \end{bmatrix}$.
$\alpha_1 = l_1 \cdot (U_R-U_L) = \frac{c_h}{2}(B_{x,R}-B_{x,L}) + \frac{1}{2}(\psi_R-\psi_L)$,
$\alpha_2 = l_2 \cdot (U_R-U_L) = -\frac{c_h}{2}(B_{x,R}-B_{x,L}) + \frac{1}{2}(\psi_R-\psi_L)$.
Then $U_m = U_L + \alpha_1 r_1$, we get
$\begin{bmatrix}B_{x,m} \\ \psi_m \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}B_{x,L} \\ \psi_L \end{bmatrix} + \left[\frac{c_h}{2}(B_{x,R}-B_{x,L}) + \frac{1}{2}(\psi_R-\psi_L)\right] \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{c_h} \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$,
So then it will be
$\begin{bmatrix}B_{x,m} \\ \psi_m \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}B_{x,L} \\ \psi_L \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}(B_{x,R}-B_{x,L}) + \frac{1}{2c_h}(\psi_R-\psi_L) \\ \frac{1}{2}(\psi_R-\psi_L) + \frac{c_h}{2}(B_{x,R}-B_{x,L}) \end{bmatrix}$.
I think this is close to equation 7 in the material, but on the RHS the third term is negative sign. And the derivation I got of which is positive sign...
